# How many event listeners in stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

With stage.numChildren I know how many objects I added to the stage, but I want to know how many addEventListener I set up.

In doing so I can monitor the memory usage. I think the project I'm working on I can't have event listener for each one object. I think I'm going to have to take advantage of arrays and loops.

Taking it into account I am also learning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep count of how many listeners you add.  "hasEventListener" is your friend in this case if you have a small select number of event types.